# Intel 330 has no support on aes 256

Tags: ssd

I was about to buy Intel 330 SSD but was stumbled upon an article saying the Sandforce controller is not capable of AES 256. Should I worry about it? What real life HDD activity uses AES 256 features?

Comment: Are you planning on use full-disk hardware encryption or not. It's kind of a yes or no thing.

Comment: No, but aside from full disk encryption, any other things i can do with aes356 in ssd stuff?

Comment: Nope, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES support in the hardware controller is used for full disk encryption (with the AES algorithm). It is put in the chip to make FDE less hard on the CPU, as it then can fully be handled by the dedicated hardware in the SSD/HDD controller. If you are not planning on using full-disk encryption, it won't matter at all, if you are planning on using it, you will only suffer a small performance penalty if you buy a SSD without hardware AES support.

**2019 update**: By now, almost all CPUs support AES-NI or similar instructions, allowing them to handle the AES workload in only a few cycles per byte. Even measuring this overhead is going to be hard. Meanwhile, [researchers have shown the hardware encryption support is often poorly implemented by drive vendors](https://www.ru.nl/english/news-agenda/news/vm/icis/cyber-security/2018/radboud-university-researchers-discover-security/). It is probably better to *never* use the built-in encryption.

Comment: Does encryption slow your speed?

Comment: When you encrypt something, you apply a complicated algorithm to the data. This work is normally done by the CPU, which means it does increase system load.